# What is a "dual-central switch"?

Tags: switch

In the following description, it states to use a switch that has uplinks to dual-central switches.  What is a "dual-central switch"?

[image]

From the book Hadoop in Practice, by Alex Holmes.

Comment: From the context, I would assume that it means switches setup for redundancy, so you can survive the failure of a single switch.  But I have not seen that terminology before.

Comment: yeah that's my guess also. I think it's a little badly written, but the intention is your central switches which have some form of redundancy.

Comment: I'd read that as being a pair of stacked switches with teamed/aggregated connections to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would interpret this to mean the network should have separate core and aggregation layers.

The Cisco [Data Center Service Patterns](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Data_Center/DC_3_0/dc_serv_pat.html) document has a good diagram of a [traditional model](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Data_Center/DC_3_0/dc_serv_pat.html#wp1007192) core/agreggation layer setup:

[image: network diagram]
<sub>(source: [cisco.com](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/i/200001-300000/220001-230000/226001-227000/226533.jpg))</sub>

This is a better alternative to a network where [switches are connected to the switches in the neighboring racks](https://github.blog/2012-12-05-network-problems-last-friday/), daisy-chaining them along and possibly causing congestion.